# Printf of Double or int

Tags: c++, memory, int, printf, double

Hello everyone,

```
      int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  double b=2;
  printf( "with the d   a = %d \n", a); // print 2
  printf( "with the d   a = %d \n", b); // **print 0  <== My interrogation?**
  printf( "with the f   a = %f", b); // print 2.000000 
  return 0;
}
```

I know that since we declare b as a double we have to use the %f in the printf function. 
My question is: deeply in the memory, **why we print a 0** since we put in b an int (even if the program has already reserve a memory for a double) ??

Thank you

Comment: You have UB, as you don't recspect `printf` format.

Comment: `deeply in the memory, why we print a 0 since we put in b an int (even if the program has already reserve a memory for a double) ??` Thats not how it works. Floating point numbers are stored totally different.

Comment: If you tag correctly c++, you might use `std::cout` instead.

Comment: You have undefined behavior, so the resulting behavior is not bound. The same code may produce different results depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Remember that `printf` is not type-safe, it has to rely only on the format specifier to get the data you pass as arguments. And if the format specifier doesn't match the argument you will have *undefined behavior* (though what probably happens is that `printf` just tries to interpret the data in the way the format specifier told it to).

Answer (score 4):

The binary represenation of `2` as a IEEE 754 double is `0x4000000000000000`, passing the `double` to printf that is expecting an `int` presumably causes a cast to an integer and only looks at the bottom 4 bytes which are all `0` so `0` is printed.

All of this is undefined behaviour so shouldn't be relied upon and you need to make sure you use the correct format strings. Some modern compilers will even warn if your format strings don't match your arguments.

Comment: This is not the reason, as the assembly code shows. Check the calling conventions on the X86 architecture - the floating point values are passed in different registers than the integers, so the zero is simply some junk. Moreover, on both Linux and mac I get random junk that changes from one run to another, not zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior (UB) since there is a mismatch between the format string and the argument. Having said that, and assuming that the compiler does not make some non-trivial transformations, then the UB has some typical behavior in this case.

To see what happens you have to check the calling convention on the system. Most likely the program run on a 64 bit x86 architecture, which passes arguments according to [X86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention). On windows, the first floating point value is passed by a different register (XMM0) than the otherwise integer argument (one of RCX, RDX, R8, R9). This means that for:

```
printf( "with the d   a = %d \n", b);
```

the `double b` is passed to one place, while the `"%d"` is reading from another. Also note that the relevant integers are considered volatile, and can be trashed by the earlier call to `printf`. This means that the int (a=2) passed to the previous `printf`, through the register, is trashed by the same `printf`. In effect, the "%d" makes `printf` read a junk value left over from the inner implementation of `printf`.

As a result, on Linux and on mac, with clang and gcc I get random junk value instead of zero. I assume that the original question is referring Visual Studio on Windows, that might set the integer to zero in debug mode (or something similar).

Please note that there is no guarantee with undefined behavior. The compiler might do anything, including removing the offending line, or doing something completely unexpected. The analysis of this answer is correct for a given compiler, system, and optimization level. It was observed in the generated assembly, but any minor change (even in other function in the code) may cause a completely different behavior. Don't ever rely on undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour.

You are asking C to look at the piece of memory occupied by your double and interpret it as if it was an int.

What is probably happening is that the double is being loaded onto the floating point registers, while printf is looking on the stack for the int value.

Any decent compiler these days should give you warnings when your format string does not match your parameter types. Always read those warnings!